# How to disable all Apex PMD warnings in VSCode?

Tags: apex, visualstudiocode, pmd

I have set the `Priority Warn Threshold` to `0`, but it will still show warnings as hints. Is it possible to not show any warnings?

And I have also created a `pmd-ruleset.xml` file, but how do I configure it to show only default PMD errors and no warnings or hints?

[image: PMD Settings]

Comment: You can use this on top of the class - @SuppressWarnings("PMD") or disable the extension

Comment: Thank you, yes I meant for the entire project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Figured it out**

By using the `Apex PMD` VSCode extension default ruleset and changing some rule priorities I can customize it for my situation

https://github.com/ChuckJonas/vscode-apex-pmd/blob/master/rulesets/apex_ruleset.xml

Alternatively the extension can be disabled to hide these warnings